# Let $X$ be a regular space and let $h:X→Y$ a homeomorphism. We will prove that $Y$ is regular.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a regular space and let $h:X→Y$ a homeomorphism. We will prove that $Y$ is regular.
Suppose that $ C $ is a closed subset of $ Y $ and that $ y \in Y \setminus C $ is an arbitrary point. Then, there exists $ x \in X $ such that $ h(x) = y $ and $ x \not\in h^{-1}(C) $. Since $ h $ is continuous, $ h^{-1}(C) $ is closed in $ X $.

Since $ X $ is regular for $x \in X$ and $x \notin h^{-1}(C)$,there are $\exists{U},{V}$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $h^{-1}(C)\subset V$ but i couldnt keep going i dont know what to do next.

Comment: Well the map is also open and closed as a homeomorphism, so you get an easy appropriate separation.

Comment: Remember that $h$ is a homeomorphism, so it preserves open sets.

Answer (score 1):

$C \subset h(V)$ , $y=h(x) \in h(U)$ and $h(U),h(V)$ are open. Also $h(U)\cap h(V)=h(U\cap V)=\emptyset$.